# Jquery validation on container.validate() instead of form.validate()

Tags: jquery, umbraco, jquery-validate

we are building a new umbraco website, which contains many registration forms and we are using Jquery validation plugin to validate these forms.

Since each usercontrol(macro) contains server tags we have to use one form in each usercontrol to get the JQuery validation to work.

But since we are using one form in each usercontrol, we can't add multiple controls in a page.

What we want to do is add a form tag with runat="server" in master page and then do all the validation with some container.validate(); instead of form.validate().

ie something like this

```
<script type="text/javascript>

    $('#regForm').validate();

</script>


<div id="regForm">

  <input type="text" class="required" name="Name" id="txtName" runat="server"/>

</div>
```

Comment: @Sparky672: what i want is do validation on some container.validate() instead of form.validate();

Comment: So the question is what?  Can you do it?  The answer is no... it needs the fields to be within a `<form>`.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

The Validation plugin needs the various fields that it's going to be validating to be contained within a set of `<form></form>` tags.

http://rocketsquared.com/wiki/Plugins/Validation

However, you can do validation without having to "submit" the form.  It can still be achieved with the `onkeyup:` or `onfocusout:` handlers for an example.

So if you can simply change your `<div id="regForm">` into something like `<form id="regForm" ... >`, you'll then be able to validate.

**EDIT:**

[For HTML 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.3), the only *required* `form` attribute is `action`, so there's no reason you can't just replace your `<div id="regForm"> </div>` with this...

```
<form id="regForm" action="#"> </form>
```

Comment: yes, that i know.. but we are searching for a method to validate on div.validate() since to avoid multiple forms in a page . thanks for your answer.

Comment: @mahesh, I fully understood your question but the answer remains the same... the Validator needs a `<form>`.

Comment: @mahesh, There is no reason to avoid multiple `<forms>` on a page.  See my edit and answer by @Gary.S

Comment: But all the forms here used are with runat="server", but we can't add multiple forms with runat="server" in a page. Also if we add a form with runat="server" in masterpage all other forms will come inside this form and i think this type of nesting is against html rules

Comment: @mahesh, there is no other way you're going to get the Validator to work without a form.  I have provided the only solution possible.

Answer (score 1):

This is a late answer, but seeing that none of the existing answers were accepted, here is my take on this. I just ran into a similar situation where I needed to validate a div contained in a form for a modal dialog. Here is how I solved it.

```
<script type="text/javascript>
  jQuery(function($) {
    $('form').validate();

    $('.continue').click(function() {
        var isValid = true;
        var $div = $(this).closest("div");
        $div.find(":input").each( function() {
           isValid = $(this).valid() && isValid;
        });
        if ( isValid ) {
           var $next = $div.hide().next('div');
           if ( $next.length == 0 ) {
              $(form).submit();
           } else {
              $next.show();
           }
        }
    });
  });
</script>

<form action="#">
    <div id="div1">
       <input type="text" required name="Name" id="txtName"        runat="server"/>
       <button class="continue">Continue</button>
    </div>
    <div id="div2">
       <input type="text" required name="Address" id="txtAddress" runat="server"/>
       <input type="text" required name="City" id="txtCity" runat="server"/>
       <input type="text" required name="State" id="txtState" runat="server"/>
       <input type="text" required name="Zip" id="txtZip" runat="server"/>
       <button class="continue">Continue</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

By default asp.net can only have one form with runat="server". You can however have multiple forms on the page as Sparky's answer shows. More info on multiple forms in asp.net can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164151.aspx.

Comment: But all the forms here used are with runat="server", but we can't add multiple forms with runat="server" in a page. Also if we add a form with runat="server" in masterpage all other forms will come inside this form and i think this type of nesting is against html rules

Comment: @mahesh, read the link posted in this answer. It tells you how to place multiple forms on the page.   There is no other way you're going to get the Validator to work.